# Use file timestamps as commit dates

Tags: git

I often work on a number of different files over some time before I get around to committing that work.
The work should then often go into multiple commits, not only one.

It would be nice if those commits would not show the *current* time, but rather a reasonable approximation of *when I actually finished the work* that is in them.
One approach for getting such an approximation would be to use the `mtime` file timestamp of the youngest file that goes into the commit.

#### Example

Assume I have worked on files `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.
`a` and `b` should go into commit 1,
`c` `d` into commit 2.

I would like to do something like this:

```
git add a b
git commit --date=files -m"modified a and b"
```

and have git use the timestamp of either `a` or `b` for the commit, whichever is younger.

As far as I can see, there is no support for this in git.
Does anybody know why? It sounds like a useful functionality to me.

Can anybody recommend a helper program that would do this?
(For the use as sketched above, this is easy, but when further changes are done to `a` or `b` after the `git add`, it becomes a lot more difficult.)

Comment: "when further changes are done to `a` or `b` after the `git add`, it becomes a lot more difficult" - I think that's an understatement: a git tree object doesn't store any file timestamps, so there is nowhere to look up "what did the file _used_ to have as its timestamp?"

Comment: ... unless you look at the date of the last commit that touched that file (following the thread rationale, right?). I don't think you will have accurate results trying to implement this but.... as it has already been said, you can always specify which date you want for a commit so it's not a technical impossibility.

Comment: @mkrieger1 More commits earlier does not work for me. I work on one main thing A and several side things B, C. Deciding that B or C are now finished and can be committed would be too distracting (e.g. because they are in the same files as already-existing parts of A), so they pile up until A is finished as well.

Comment: @LutzPrechelt A commit, particularly on a local branch you haven't shared anywhere, doesn't have to mean that something is finished; it just means it's in a state that you might want to remember something about. I'm not sure what time frame you're talking about in your example, but I would consider it worrying if I'd been working for more than a few hours without creating at least one commit, even if I was nowhere near a working solution. Once the solution was working, I would decide which parts of the history I wanted to share and make permanent by merging onto a main branch.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different scenarios you talk about here, one of which is fairly easy to implement yourself, and the other is basically impossible, but also easily avoided.

Scenario 1 is that you've made some changes to files `a` and `b`, but forgotten to commit, then come back after editing *other* files, and want to record when you actually did the work. As you say, this is relatively straight-forward to write a helper for. For instance using `stat -c '%Y' filename` will give a Unix timestamp, which can be sorted and passed to `git commit`:

```
git commit --date="$(stat -c '%Y' file1 file2 | sort -n | tail -n1)"
```

Scenario 2 is that you've made the changes, run `git add`, and then carried on working *on the same files* without committing. Since a git tree (including the Staging area) doesn't store modification timestamps, there is no way that any tool can answer the question "what was this file's timestamp when I ran `git add`?"

However, what *does* have a timestamp is a git *commit*, and commits are *cheap*, so you just need to adjust your habits so that after running `git add`, you run something like:

```
git commit -m WIP
```

Now you have a snapshot of the files, with a timestamp against it! Later, you can run `git rebase -i` and for each "WIP" commit, set it to either:

- "reword" to give it a proper message
- "fixup" or "squash" to combine into fewer commits